# La tournure « Pas tout le monde (ne) peut… » est-elle correcte ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, adverbes, syntaxe

Je pense que nous avons tous rencontré le cas de la tournure donnée en titre. Nous connaissons aussi les tournures équivalentes acceptées :

> Ce n'est pas tout le monde qui peut…
>
> Tout le monde ne peut pas…

La tournure « Pas tout le monde (ne) peut… » semble profondément fausse sans que je puisse l'expliquer ou trouver une règle qui dise pourquoi.

**Quelqu'un aurait-il la raison qui me permette de justifier l'incorrection de cette tournure ?**

Si l'une des deux versions « Pas tout le monde peut… » ou « Pas tout le monde ne peut… » *est* correcte, merci également d'expliquer pourquoi.

Comment: Personnellement, je trouve que *"Pas tout le monde peut"* sonne juste dans le sens ou c'est un raccourci de langage pour dire *"Ce n'est pas tout le monde qui peut…"*

Comment: @YohannV. Et j'ai par conséquent adapté la question. :) (et supprimé le commentaire précédent pour limiter la pollution)

Comment: Peut être que ce n'a tout simplement pas le même sens (même si subtile ?). Peut-être que "Pas tout le monde" insiste sur le peu de personne qui peuvent, alors que "Tout le monde ne peut pas" insiste sur la difficulté, non ? (Je sais pas pourquoi, mais je sens que c'est moi qui t'ai inspiré la question non ??? :D )

Comment: @Random Tout à fait. :) J'ai essayé de chercher un peu avant la modification que tu as approuvée et Google semble s'accorder sur le fait que c'est incorrect, mais personne n'explique _pourquoi_. Cela semble seulement admis.

Comment: En effet, Google semble ne pas aimer. Pourtant cette formulation ne me choque absolument pas, et j'ai l'impression de l'entendre très régulièrement à l'oral. Je pense que @YohannV. tient une possible explication pour une contraction de "Ce n'est pas tout le monde qui peut..."

Comment: @Random Oui, cette forme est généralement utilisée avec ce rôle, mais en attendant qu'elle soit homologuée par l'Académie française, ce n'est pour moi qu'un choix de facilité. J'ai peut-être trouvé une piste en étudiant l'usage de « pas », je ne sais pas ce que vous en pensez.

Comment: Au contraire de Yohann V., cette tournure me choque assez cruellement, tout du moins sous la forme « Pas tout le monde peut... », peut être parce qu'il ne me viendrait pas non plus à l'idée de dire « Ce n'est pas tout le monde qui peut... » quand il « Tout le monde ne peut pas... » vient plus facilement à la bouche. Evidemment, rien ne sert d'ergoter sur nos préférences personnelles si nous n'avons pas de source solide derrière.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues *"Ce n'est pas ... qui ..."* marque un emphase ([extraction](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphase_%28linguistique%29#L.27extraction)) qui met en relief ce dont on parle, bien plus qu'une simple négation. La formulation "Pas *tout le monde* peut", formulation du langage courant et semblant incorrecte, conserve l'importance donnée au groupe nominal *"tout le monde"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Une piste qui semblerait probante est l'utilisation de « pas ».

[Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas#Adverbe) en donne trois définitions :

1. Négation d'un verbe :

   > Tu ne **manges** pas.
   >   Je ne **veux** pas travailler.
   >   Tu n'**as** pas idée.
2. Négation réthorique (l'exemple donné porte toujours sur un verbe) :

   > N'**est**-elle pas jolie ?
3. Négation d'un épithète :

   > Un logement pas **cher**.

On constate que jamais « pas » ne porte sur un *nom*<sup>1</sup>. Or, **« tout le monde » étant une locution nominale, « pas » ne peut s'y appliquer.**

Par conséquent, toutes les formes de tournure « Pas tout le monde » sont bel et bien incorrectes.

---

<sub>1. Il est possible de trouver « [pas un](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas_un) ». Dans ce cas, nous n'examinons plus l'adverbe « pas » mais un article indéfini équivalent dans — son sens et son usage — à « aucun » (exemple du wiktionnaire : « De toutes ces photos, pas une n'est belle. »). Ceci ne paraît donc pas apporter d'éclairage différent pour notre question.</sub>

Comment: Ça me parait être une bonne raison ! ;)

Comment: Et pourtant, pas un argument qui me convainque. Je ne suis pas sûr que cette explication suffise ! (en fait, il semblerait que "pas un" soit un adjectif indéfini, voir http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/indefinis.php).

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues La question fait [débat](http://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=76202&titre=Tout+le+monde+%2B+n%E9gation) entre ceux qui pensent la tournure correcte et ceux partisans du contraire. C'est pour cela que je suis à la recherche de la règle qui sous-tend la (non-)validité de l'expression.

Comment: @Chop J'ai bien compris la question ! Je voulais juste signaler la phrase « jamais "pas" ne porte sur un *nom* » n'était pas entièrement vraie, puisqu'on peut écrire « pas un mot »... Mais il s'avère que « pas un » est en réalité un adjectif indéfini, et on ne peut pas écrire, à ma connaissance, « pas le... ».

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues C'est juste. Il est possible de dire « Pas le mien », mais cela reste une contraction de « Ce que tu as dit ne concerne pas le mien. » J'ajoute une remarque concernant « pas un ». Merci.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues il y a aussi "pas le moins du monde" en répondant à une question... (qui soulève une nouvelle formulation intéressante, n'est-ce pas ?)

Comment: @Random Intéressant effectivement, mais qui ne m'aide toujours pas. D'abord parce qu'[il s'agit d'une locution adverbiale](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas_le_moins_du_monde) donc construction invariable et pas forcément réutilisable, ensuite parce qu'elle porte sur un verbe omis, comme dans mon exemple avec « Pas le mien. » J'avoue que je sèche que ce soit pour justifier dans un sens comme dans l'autre.

Comment: Au _LBU_ on voit que la négation est construite différemment selon qu'on est en présence d'un verbe ou pas. Et dans un monde sans verbe, des limites ? Pas question. Quand on est à cheval entre le verbal et l'averbal, ça énerve. Peut-être qu'on a aussi  l'influence de l'interrogation à l'ancienne que _Vaugelas_ aimait tant, sans « ne », mais avec sens positif, comme « _Viens-tu pas demander asile ?_ » (Hugo). À l'oral on s'en permet, mais à l'écrit avec un phrase complète, à moins qu'on rapporte l'oral, on fait preuve de davantage de rigueur, à mon avis. Merci.

Comment: @Chop mais que dire du rôle de 'pas' dans la phrase "l'instructeur forme le maître, mais pas le chien" dans ce cas?

Comment: Pour moi, il s'agit avant tout de formules orales pour éviter les lourdeurs ou les répétitions (et en français, il est clair que l'on n'aime pas les répétitions). *"l'instructeur forme le maître, mais [ne forme] pas le chien"*. Donc il s'agit d'une négation classique. De même pour "*[Ce n'est p]Pas tout le monde [qui] peut"*

Comment: @vc74 Je suis tout à fait d'accord avec YohannV. sur l'interprétation de ton exemple : on « ellipse » le verbe pour ne pas le répéter. Moins convaincu par son interprétation de « Pas tout le monde peut ».

Comment: oui ça se tient

Comment: @Chop Je comprends, et je n'ai rien pour étayer mon explication, alors je ne suis pas vexé. Je voulais quand même donner mon sentiment. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Pour moi, quand tu dis:
Tout le monde ne vient pas, ça veut dire personne ne vient car tout le monde est positif et englobe toutes les personnes et ne est négatif. Donc la réponse est plutôt claire pour moi quant à la tournure qui est correcte.  En effet, pas tout le monde indique que pas toutes les personnes viennent et donc une double négation n'est pas obligatoire pour que la phrase soit correcte car la phrase n'est pas négative.
J'espère que je t'ai aidé!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bonjour Nathan. Merci de contribuer. Attention toutefois à répondre à la question. Ici : la tournure "pas tout le monde peut…" est-elle correcte ? Pour revenir sur un élément du post de question, le mieux est de le faire sous forme de commentaire. Pour que tes réponses reçoivent davantage de votes positifs, tu peux aussi essayer de citer des sources.

Comment: Je te rejoins sur le fait que "Pas tout le monde ne peut…" semble plus faux que sa version sans double négation, cependant. Concernant "Tout le monde ne peut pas…", j'ai une interprétation différente (la négation de "tout" n'est pas "rien", c'est "pas tout", donc "Tout le monde ne peut pas…" ne représente pas pour moi la même chose que "Personne ne peut…").